# How to calculate between differences of 2 Integer value in SELECT statement in Azure SQL?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have Query:

```
SELECT [Asia_Sales],[Europe_Sales] FROM [dbo].[CustomerSales]
```

Query return 2 integer values.

I would like to calculate Asia_Sales minus Europe_Sales? I would insert to INT column of database.

```
SELECT [Asia_Sales],[Europe_Sales], [Sales_Difference] FROM [dbo].[CustomerSales]
```

Comment: `[Asia_Sales] - [Europe_Sales] as Sales_Difference` ???

Answer (score 0):

I tried below syntax on sample data and it is working for me:

[image]

The below statement should work for you.

`SELECT [Asia_Sales] - [Europe_Sales] AS [Difference] FROM [dbo].[CustomerSales];`

Comment: Hi, if you find this answer helpful and it resolved your issue, please accept it as an answer (click on check mark on left side of answer) to help other community members.